# Android accelerometer data to Arduino

Tags: android, arduino, accelerometer

I'm using an Android phone as a remote control for a robot using an Arduino micro-controller. The app works as expected and sends x and y axis data from the accelerometer to the Arduino robot.

The problem is that the app just freezes sometimes (usually after a couple minutes). The x and y axis data that is being sent to the robot is also displayed on the screen of the Android phone, and I can see that the x and y axis data does not change. If I just connect the Android to the Arduino robot without turning on the power to the motors, it stays connected and sends data for hours at a time without freezing.

The Android seems to crash only when I am using the phone as a remote control with the motors turned on. That makes no sense to me that the motors (EMI) could interfere with the Android app. The Arduino sends NO data back to the Android. Any ideas?

```
package com.example.shiel.sonicartrc;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class SendData extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    Button btnOn, btnOff, btnDis;
    float x, y;
    String address = null;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private boolean isBtConnected = false;
    static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    //MOTION STARTS
    //private static final String TAG = ledControl.class.getSimpleName();
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    TextView tv, tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent newint = getIntent();
        address = newint.getStringExtra(BTdevices.EXTRA_ADDRESS);
        //receive the address of the bluetooth device
        //view of the ledControl
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_data);
        //call the widgets
        btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btnDis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        //MOTION START
        //get the sensor service
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        //get the accelerometer sensor
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        //get layout
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xval);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yval);
        Log.d("TAG", "My debug-message4");
        //MOTION END

        new ConnectBT().execute(); //Call the class to connect
        //commands to be sent to bluetooth
        btnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                turnOnLed(); //method to turn on
            }
        });

        btnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                turnOffLed();   //method to turn off
            }
        });

        btnDis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Disconnect(); //close connection
            }
        });
    }

    private void Disconnect() {
        if (btSocket != null) {
          //If the btSocket is busy
            try {
                btSocket.close(); //close connection
            } catch (IOException e) {
                msg("Error");
            }
        }
        finish(); //return to the first layout
    }

    private void turnOffLed() {
        if (btSocket != null) {
            try {
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write("<a>".getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                msg("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    private void turnOnLed() {
        if (btSocket != null) {
            try {
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write("<b>".getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                msg("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendMotor(String cmdSendLR) {
        if (btSocket != null) {
            try {
                btSocket.getOutputStream().write(cmdSendLR.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                msg("Error");
            } finally{
                 btSocket.close();
            }
        }
    }

    // fast way to call Toast
    private void msg(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        // UI thread
        private boolean ConnectSuccess = true; //if it's here, it's almost connected
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(SendData.this, "Connecting", "Please wait");  //show a progress dialog
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) {
            //while the progress dialog is shown, the connection is done in background
            try {
                if (btSocket == null || !isBtConnected) {
                    myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    //get the mobile bluetooth device
                    BluetoothDevice dispositive = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);
                    //connects to the device's address and checks if it's available
                    btSocket = dispositive.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
                    //create a RFCOMM (SPP) connection
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                    btSocket.connect();//start connection
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ConnectSuccess = false;//if the try failed, you can check the exception here
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //after the doInBackground, it checks if everything went fine
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (!ConnectSuccess) {
                msg("Connection Failed");
                finish();
            } else {
                msg("Connected");
                isBtConnected = true;
            }
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    }

    //MOTION STARTS
    @Override
    public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
    }

    @Override
    public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        WindowManager windowMgr = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        int rotationIndex = windowMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        if (rotationIndex == 1 || rotationIndex == 3) {
            // detect 90 or 270 degree rotation
            x = -event.values[1];
            y = event.values[0];
        } else {
            x = event.values[0]; //Force x axis in m s-2
            y = event.values[1]; //Force y axis in m s-2
        }
        sendEventValues();
    }

    public void sendEventValues() {
        tv.setText("X axis" + "\t\t" + x);
        tv1.setText("Y axis" + "\t\t" + y);
        if (isBtConnected) {
            int xx = Math.round(x);
            int yy = Math.round(y);
            sendMotor("<" + xx + "," + yy + ">");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
    //MOTION ENDS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you are not closing your sockets. You need to OPEN your socket, send the data and then close it.

```
try {
 ...
}finally{
   try {
      mSocket.close();
   } catch (IOException closeException) { }
```

Just to clarify. If you don't close a socket, your program will leak a file descriptor. That's not immediate so that's why you see it freezing after a while.

Comment: I modified the `sendMotor` method above. Is that what you were getting at? If so, I need to modify the `turnOnLed` and `turnOffLed` methods as well. I am at work, so I can't test this at the moment, but I would like to know if I am on the right track.

Comment: @DanielShields don't forget to share here the result as well as flag this answer as correct.

Comment: does that look correct to you in the `sendMotor` method? I've looked at many other examples and the developer documentation, and I don't see anybody doing anything like that.

Comment: doesn't compile

Comment: any other answers? That answer doesn't seem to be even close.

Comment: Have you at least read the error to say why "it does not compile"? You need to handle IOException when closing sockets. Actually it seems very clear to me that you are leaking of file descriptor.

Comment: The app will connect to the arduino bluetooth, but it won't send data. I get the error message on my phone, and it won't go away until I force close the app. So how do I handle leaking file descriptor?

Comment: Can you point to me an example of what my code should read? I can't find any, and I have been looking for hours.

Comment: You need to better structure your serial connection handling strategy. Search for sockets in Java and try to understand them. I came across with this document explaining how to use Android Bluetooth API to send/receive data. Might be helpful http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring14/group01/docs/appnote/Wirsing-SendingAndReceivingDataViaBluetoothWithAnAndroidDevice.pdf

Comment: can you point out to me where my code is wrong and where it deviates from the code that I see in many many other examples? if not, I think I'll wait for the next person to answer, but thanks for your time